# When was the Illudium Q-36 Space Modulator first depicted?

Tags: cartoon, plot-device, looney-tunes

The *Illudium Q-36 Space Modulator* was an explosive device meant to destroy the Earth, which was blocking Marvin the Martian's view of Venus. It may have also been mentioned with a different but similar sounding name, with variants such as *Uranium* and *Pu-36*.

This is the episode where I first saw the the attempted "Earth shattering Kaboom!" but I don't know when this was aired, or if this is even the first time it was depicted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The first reference to the Modulator

The first reference to the Q-36, which is referred to as the "Uranium PU-36 Explosive Space Modulator", because *Looney Tunes* is nothing without its strict canon, is also the first appearance of Marvin himself.

The episode is called *Haredevil Hare*, and it was first broadcast in 1948; you can watch the full episode [at DailyMotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2fbylh).

Because I have a compulsive need to cite my sources, here's the 2016 book [*Mars in the Movies: A History*](https://www.amazon.ca/Mars-Movies-Thomas-Kent-Miller/dp/0786499141):

> #### *Haredevil Hare* (1948)
>
> **Summary:** Bugs Bunny is dragged kicking and screaming towards the moon rocket, but when he sees a load of carrots being dumped into the rocket, he changes his mind and becomes the first rabbit shot into space. No sooner does he arrive on the moon than a rocket emblazoned with *Mars to Moon Expeditionary Force*lands nearby. It so happens that the odd little pilot of that ship is unhappy that the Earth blocks his view of Venus, so he intends to blow up the Earth with his Uranium Pew-36 Explosive Space Modulator. Bugs foils this plan by inadvertently blowing up the moon instead.
>
> <sup>[*Mars in the Movies: A History* Chapter 4: "Invasions From Mars"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Y7R5DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT143&lpg=PT143&dq=haredevil%20hare%20release%20date&source=bl&ots=BBPTQ-1YcC&sig=KylyFoUYi78aO_UxFzAlUQ8maQU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiam5P9xLDRAhUQ-2MKHTMFDD04ChDoAQhCMAo#v=onepage&q=haredevil%20hare&f=false)</sup>

### The episode you watched

The episode you recall, and which you've provided a video to, is the later (1958) cartoon *Hare-Way to the Stars*; the full episode is also [on DailyMotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3uysut).

Comment: Do we need a new tag?

Comment: @Adamant To my astonishment, we already have a [tag:looney-tunes] tag

Comment: Citations are always appreciated, and I'm really happy to see the tag - I wasn't sure how this question would fly. Wow watching a moon landing from 1948 in 2017! (I got started thinking about Marvin today [here](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/19708/12102).) Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: Man, I have to grow up sometime :|

Comment: [What do these GPS-related emblems represent? Does one of them show “Marvin the Martian”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29434/12102)